# Query to select strings end with certain character

Tags: mysql

I have a column that contains strings as:

```
aaa_1
aaa_11
```

I need to query strings that ends with `_1`. I tried the following:
select col from table where col like `%_1`;
But the query gives me the strings that ends with `_1` and `_11`. How can I correct this ?

Comment: `%_1` won't give you `%_11`, though `%_1%` would.

Comment: like %_1 should return just the first, like %_1% should return both. What database are you using?

Comment: You may also do `WHERE RIGHT(the_column, 2) = '_1'`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
select col from table where col like '%\_1'
```

character `_` is a jolly, like %, but it matches only a single character, so you have to escape it with `\`

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: wouldnt this also match something like a_1aaa

Comment: @dgarg there's a single wildchar % at the beginning of the string, so it would only match strings ending with _1, if you wanto to match a_1aaa you have to use `like '%\_1%`

Answer (score 26):

You'll want to use something more substring related.

Try a where clause like:

```
SELECT col from table WHERE RIGHT(col, 2) = '_1'
```

Comment: This is the right solution if we want to ensure that _1 is only at the end of the col value

Comment: Which is exactly what the original question was?

"I need to query strings that ends with _1". Right?

That said, the solution by fthiella above is probably the better one, and likely more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers!

My answer is an extension from the other posts.

In case you want to filter out data that is ending with specific character(s), use `REGEXP` operator.
Example : below query returns all strings where ending character(s) is/are vowel -

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name REGEXP ".*[a,e,i,o,u]{n}$"     -- n = number of vowels at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `%` and `_` by adding backslash `\` as they are wildcards in mysql:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

```
String |     Description
\%     |     Matches one “%” character
\_     |     Matches one “_” character
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of these will pick up things like `%_12` or `%_111121`, etc. Make sure you test out various cases to be sure these `SELECT` statements are giving you the proper subset.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '_1[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a quick use of this query to filter out strings ending with specific character(s). 
The below query output will give all names ending with 'er'.

```
select column_name
from table
where column_name regexp '.*er$';
```